# Component is not Getting Rendered - Dynamic Routing React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I can get the data of the players  when i Route to the Players Component, 
but when i click on the Link Tags, the PLayersContainer Component is not opening.
This is my App.js File.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import Players from './Components/Players'
import PlayersContainer from './Components/Container/playersContainer'
import Navigation from './Components/Navigation';
export default class App extends Component {

    state = {

      players:[

        {
          id:1,
          name:'Ronaldo'
        },
        {
          id:2,
          name:'Messi'
        }

      ]
}


  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
          <Navigation />
          <Switch>
          <Route  path="/players" render={(props) => <Players {...props}  players={this.state.players} />} />
          <Route exact path="/players/:id" render={PlayersContainer} />
          </Switch>
    </Router>
    )
  }
}
```

This is my Players Component.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function Players(props) {

    const renderPlayers = () => {

        let players = props.players.map(playerObj => <li> <Link to={`/players/${playerObj.id}`}> Player {playerObj.name} </Link></li>)
        return players
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            {renderPlayers()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is my PlayersContainer Component, where i want to render the individual data of the Player.

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
export default function PlayersContainer(props) {


    const renderPlayers = () => {

        console.log(props);
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ul>
            {renderPlayers()}
            </ul>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the wrong `Route` marked as `exact`. The way its written currently, anything beginning with `/players` will match the first route. Since its in a switch, only the first match will be rendered.

Change it from:

```js
<Route path="/players" render={(props) => <Players {...props}  players={this.state.players} />} />
<Route exact path="/players/:id" render={PlayersContainer} />
```

to this:

```js
<Route exact path="/players" render={(props) => <Players {...props}  players={this.state.players} />} />
<Route path="/players/:id" render={PlayersContainer} />
```

Now only exactly `/players` will match the first route, and `/players/id` can continue past it to match the second.

Comment: yes its working now.. but what if i give exact strict to both the Routes?? even that is working.                      <Route exact strict  path="/players" render={(props) => <Players {...props}  players={this.state.players} />} />
     <Route exact strict path="/players/:id" render={PlayersContainer} />

Comment: Without referencing the docs or trying it out, I don't remember how it would handle an exact route with a dynamic path. But you can try it

Comment: if i give "exact strict" to both of the routes , it is working. dont know if that is the right practice, but i guess it is stricting checking the route due to that, and i am getting a console.log now. i can fetch the Params which i want in the PlayersContainer, which solved the problem. Thank you anyways Brain. You saved me another cup of coffee for today :)